# How to distinguish between saved segment and alternative?

Tags: regex

From the following text...

```
Acme Inc.<SPACE>12345<SPACE or TAB>bla bla<CRLF>
```

... I need to extract company name + zip code + rest of the line.

Since either a TAB or a SPACE character can separate the second from the third tokens, I tried using the following regex:

```
FIND:^(.+) (\d{5})(\t| )(.+)$
REPLACE:\1\t\2\t\3
```

However, the contents of the alternative part is put in the \3 part, so the result is this:

```
Acme Inc.<TAB>12345<TAB><TAB or SPACE here>$
```

How can I tell the (Perl) regex engine that (\t| ) is an alternative instead of a token to be saved in RAM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
^(.+?) (\d{5})[\t ](.+)$
```

Since you are matching one character or the other, you can use a character class instead. Also, I made your first quantifier non-greedy (`+?` instead of `+`) to reduce the amount of backtracking the engine has to do to find the match.

In general, if you want to make capture groups not capture anything, you can add `?:` to it, like:

```
^(.+?) (\d{5})(?:\t| )(.+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use non-capturing parentheses:

```
^(.+) (\d{5})(?:\t| )(.+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `\s` instead of `( |\t)` which will match **any** whitespace char.

See [Backslash-sequences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences) for how Perl defines "whitespace".